# Complex limit of an exponential.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For which values of $\arg(z)=k$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}$ does
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty}|e^z|$$ exist? Consider $k$ constant.
I don't have any idea on how to do this. Anyone can please help me?

Comment: what does a complex number tending to infinity mean??? i.e you cant compare reals over complex. I think you mean mod(z) tending to infinity

Comment: @PrayasAgrawal $\infty$ is a perfectly fine point in complex analysis..

Comment: Hmm..... Interesting

Comment: @Stefano I think he is possibly refering to the fact that the complex numbers aren't ordered, but in fact the notation is used to *mean* taking both the limit on the real axis and on the imaginary axis

Comment: @Ragnar1204: Presumably, what you are trying to express is that the limit should be restricted to $\arg(z) = k$.

Comment: @ig: That's not true! Any neighborhood of $\infty$ contains points whose imaginary component is zero, and also points whose real component is zero. So to show a limit at $\infty$ exists, it is not sufficient to compute a limit as the magnitudes of the real and imaginary parts go to $+ \infty$

Comment: @PrayasAgrawal: The sets with $|z| > M$ do indeed serve as neighborhoods of $\infty$. But it is also true that the single point $\infty$ of the projective complex numbers doesn't mesh especially well with the two separate points $\pm \infty$ of the extended real numbers.

Comment: Since they are talking about $\arg(z)=k$, I believe they are interested in $z=re^{ik}$. That is, $$\lim_{r\to\infty}\left|e^{re^{ik}}\right|$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have

$$\vert e^z\vert =\vert e^{x+iy}\vert=e^x$$

where $x$ is the real part of $z$ and $y$ is imaginary part.

So you have for all $k=\mathrm{arg}(z)\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$:

$$\lim_{\vert z\vert \to\infty} \vert e^z\vert =\lim_{x\to+\infty} e^x=+\infty$$

because $x\to\infty$ when $\vert z\vert\to\infty$ in that case (you assumed $k$ is constant in your question).

Otherwise, if $k=\pi/2$ or $k=-\pi/2$:

$$\lim_{\vert z\vert \to\infty} \vert e^z\vert =\lim_{x\to+\infty} 1=1.$$

And finally, if $k\in(\pi/2,2\pi/2)$:

$$\lim_{\vert z\vert \to\infty} \vert e^z\vert =\lim_{x\to+\infty} e^{-x}=0.$$

So the limit will always exist if you assume $k$ **constant** (it is different if you don't).

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

$$|e^z| = \left|  e^{|z|(\cos k + i \sin k)}\right|  = \left |e^{|z| \cos k} \right| \left|  e^{i |z|\sin k}\right|.$$

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

write $e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy}$ so that : $|e^z|=e^x$