# What is $\lim\limits_{z\to\infty} \exp(z)$ with $z \in \mathbb C$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits, exponential-function, infinity

Is the exponential function even defined in the infinity point? I´ve read that it's conventionally defined equal to zero but it doesn´t make sense to me because the function is , so the limit must be the same for every path, therefore if the limit would be actually zero, when I approach for the real axis the limit would be $\infty \ne 0$, which is an absurd.

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212798/complex-limit-of-an-exponential

Comment: Limits don’t care if the function is defined there. The corrrect question is whether there is any possible value at $\infty$ which we *can* define there and keep it continuous.

Comment: Where did you see it defined as $0?$ The only place where that might be true is at $-\infty$ on the extended real line, but that is not the same as $\infty$ on the complex numbers.